# Find categories of a word in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to find categories of a word in Python.

For ex-

```
  age = young,old
```

I have tried using wordnet from NLTK but couldn't find something satisfactory.

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to find categories of a word using some dataset? What is your dataset?

Comment: Word will come dynamically. is there any nlp library that can find categories of a given word like using wordnet from nltk corpus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive but simple approach would be to have a `dict` with the mapping between the words and its categories:

```
categories = {
    'age': ('young', 'old'),
    'sex': ('male', 'female'),
    'height': ('short', 'tall')
}
```

Then you can just access them with the given word, e.g. `categories['age']`

Comment: Hey thanks for replying so fast, but I am trying to achieve this through a built in  library,like wordnet from nltk corpus